# Rails passing integer value from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have to add a view where user will enter a number and we will respond according to that number. Here I am asking a number from user and if he submit it we will generate number of paragraph for that.

Getting error **undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass** in _show_data.html.erb file

Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
private
    def baconipsum
        @baconipsum ||= Faraday.new("https://baconipsum.com/") do |f|
          f.response :json
        end
      end
end
```

Articles Controller.rb

```
def showData
    @value = params[:value] 
@bacon = baconipsum.get("api/", type: 'all-meat',paras: @value).body
  end
```

_form_data.html.erb

```
<%= form_for:article do %>
    <label for="value">Value</label>
    <%= text_field_tag :value %>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

_show_data.html.erb

```
    <% @bacon.each do |meat| %>
  <p><%= meat %></p>
<%end%>
```

Comment: you should probably be more specific with your question, mainly, an example of what you want to do when the controller responds, or how it responds.  And you should also post example code of what you have tried.  Without these things, your question could possibly be closed.

Comment: hey, i have updated my question, Kindly check it.

Comment: What issue are you facing with this code?

Comment: i am getting such error undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casing maters **a lot** in Rails. No filename should *ever* contain a capital letter, and filenames like `showData` should *never* exist. This isn't a case of opinion, this is required for Rails to correctly infer the names of files from the names of models.

Your filename names should be `_form_data.html.erb` and `_show_data.html.erb`. Wherever you're calling `render 'showData'`, this must also be changed to `render 'show_data'`. That call may be happening indirectly.

Comment: Thank you, I got in but now i am getting such error
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: and also getting error while passing the value from view: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/articles/2"):